# SingleChildScrollView , Problem with spaces on the child Column

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, singlechildscrollview

I had a **BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY ** PIXELS** when i tried to open the phone keyboard so i wrapped my Column in a **SingleChildScrollView** But somehow it became pushed to the top and the **MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly** stopped working so i made some space between them using **SizedBox**
my question is : **is that the good way to do it ? to achieve space between the widgets and is it gonna work on different phone sizes**

***my code :***
[image]

second question : how can i push all the column to the top until last item is showing **without scrolling**  when i open the keyboard like the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. To make the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` work again, you need to wrap your inside a `ConstrainedBox` to be like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text('data'),
              Text('HelloWorld'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

2. To scroll to the end of your form, use a `ScrollController` for the `SingleChildScrollView` and animate to the end of the list like this:

```
   controller.animateTo(
      controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
```

3. It's okay to use `SizedBox` for spaces, A small Tip: remember to set `const` before it to make your app more performant, cuz this way flutter won't rebuild the sizedBox Widget every time your widget is rebuilt

Hope you find this helpful =D

Comment: Hi, how do we prevent the Column go overflow? I have followed your answer but the edge case appear when my text is long enough to make overflow.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your text by `expaned` widget?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not about text. It's about children in a column will break the column. But I found the solution by wrapping `SingleChildScrollView` by `expanded` Widget. Thank for the response.

Comment: What if more content is available it will over flow on small device then how you will manage this, In my case it is hapenning

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using a `ListView`, that should solve the problem of your keyboard hidding your form fields.

About the `SizedBox` and the issues with the distribution of you widget, that is because normally when you create a column, it uses the entire hight of the parent, but in the case of the `SingleChildScrollView`, it does not have a size to give you, hence the column doesnt know how to distribute your children.

Finally, I've seen a lot of developers use the `SizedBox` to create spacing, so I dont think there is nothing wrong with using it. You could also create a `ListView.separated` ([official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html#widgets.ListView.separated.1)) which will add a the same Widget (that you provide) as a separator.